# Phantomjs changing text symbols

Tags: unicode, command-line, phantomjs

I am having an issue with PhantomJS (version 2.1.1/MAMP), it's garbling some symbols given when we are using with phantomjs.

```
I have the following UTF-8 character
---------------------------------------
ตัวละคร
---------------------------------------
```

When I tried this command,

> phantomjs rasterize.js encoded.html 001.png

**encoded.html** contains the binary codes of the above word.

But the phantomjs command returns me the distorted text as below.

[image]

This is working as expected in my local MAMP server. But in server, I am getting the modified text.

I really appreciate any help or suggestions on what is the issue here.

Comment: Different fontconfig and font used. You can confirm with `strace -ff -e openat` and look which files were opened. If that hypotheses is true, then the easiest way to fix the problem is to install a known good font on the server and change the HTML/CSS so that the font is used.

Comment: Thanks @daxim for your response. What this command will do? I did this in my mac `dtruss -ff -e openat` it results nothing but ` DTrace requires additional privileges`